ngrok problem. Problem with page redirection on localhost and bootstrap library
I'm a beginner website designer. I need to publish a website, it is multi-page. I do this using ngrok and xamp. Problem number one. The bootstrap library is not displayed. I have it connected in the code, but it is not visible on the local host. For example, there is a carousel taken from bootstrap, but ngrok does not see it. Problem number two is page redirects. Individual pages work. Side-by-side pages also switch among themselves, but they do not switch from the main page to the side-by-side pages and from the side-by-side pages to the main page. request error. I ask for help, if anyone understands what this is and how to fix it
I thought the problem was in the page titles, because the other ones switch between each other, but this does not affect, they told me that I need to download some kind of file package, but I don’t understand which one and why

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
